# Send files through post http to https website

Tags: http, iis, file-upload, https

I have a program which creates files on my domain.

The files have to be uploaded and sent to a website `https:\\upload.anothercompany.com`.

I have to copy the files to another server which have the Internet connection and then somehow upload these files to the website through HTTP POST request.

Any idea what is needed to be done? Do I need to build a website in IIS?

Comment: You can use api to upload  file to the server

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain more?